# Query division returns 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query that devide 2 columns, I tried `CAST` and `CONVERT` but still returns 0. Will apperciate your help

```
SELECT a.Disposition,a.[Disposition Reason Breakdown],a.CSP,b.Total FROM
(
SELECT a.[Disposition],a.[Disposition Reason Breakdown],a.[CSP] FROM
(
SELECT [Disposition],[Disposition Reason Breakdown],COUNT(*) as CSP FROM [dbo].[Disposition]
WHERE [Disposition] <> 'Interested'
GROUP BY [Disposition],[Disposition Reason Breakdown]
) a
)a
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT a.Disposition,SUM(a.CSP) as Total FROM 
(
SELECT [Disposition],[Disposition Reason Breakdown],COUNT(*) as CSP FROM [dbo].[Disposition]
WHERE [Disposition] <> 'Interested'
GROUP BY [Disposition],[Disposition Reason Breakdown]
)a
GROUP BY a.Disposition
)b ON a.Disposition = b.Disposition
```

I am using sql

Comment: Which numbers are you trying to divide? What are their data types?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it, it turns out that I just used the wrong data type which in my case is `decimal` I should've thought of `REAL` here is the final query `a.CSP/CAST(b.Total as REAL)`

Comment: Don't use REAL. It's imprecise. Use DECIMAL or NUMERIC